# C# MySQLDataReader.AffectedRows = -1

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

In my MySQL console, i can see the results of `select Price from rates order by id`, I get this:

```
mysql> select Price from rates order by id;
+-------+
| Price |
+-------+
| 100   |
| 120   |
| 150   |
| 200   |
| 350   |
| 700   |
| 500   |
| 700   |
| 800   |
| 1300  |
| 1500  |
| 7000  |
| 8000  |
| 15000 |
| 20000 |
+-------+
15 rows in set
```

but when I run it in this method as the *string* ***command***;

```
public List<string[]> ExecuteQuery(string command)
{
    com = new MySqlCommand(command, con);
    reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        List<string[]> records = new List<string[]>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string[] row = new string[reader.FieldCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.RecordsAffected; i++)
                row[i] = reader[i].ToString();
            records.Add(row);
        }
        reader.Close();
        return records;
    }
    else
    {
        reader.Close();
        return new List<string[]>();
    }
}
```

the `reader.AffectedRows` is -1 and it messes up the whole process...
But this one works just fine...

```
MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("select Access from useraccounts where Username = '" + tbxUsername.Text + "' and Pass = '" + tbxPassword.Text + '\'', d.con);
object result = com.ExecuteScalar();
```

I am using this connection string: `datasource = 192.168.43.191; database = database_name; user = user_name; password = pass_word;` in a Visual Studio 2015 and XAMPP with Apache and MySQL running.
This is the first time I've encountered this problem. I hope you can help

Comment: Where are you checking `reader.AffectedRows` in the code? What is your expectations from this code?

Comment: I'm checking it via breakpoints and hovering the mouse on the `reader` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RecordsAffected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected(v=vs.110).aspx) is set when your query is an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query not when your query is a SELECT one. In your code it seems that you want to use the [FieldCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string[] row = new string[reader.FieldCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            row[i] = reader[i].ToString();
        records.Add(row);
    }
```

You can also change your code to this shorter one

```
public List<string[]> ExecuteQuery(string command)
{
    List<string[]> records = new List<string[]>();
    using(com = new MySqlCommand(command, con))
    using(reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string[] row = new string[reader.FieldCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount i++)
                row[i] = reader[i].ToString();
            records.Add(row);
        }
    }
    return records;
}
```

However, in general, I recommend to avoid these *do it all* methods that cannot be able to handle, in the most performant way, the many different kind of queries required by an application.

For example the method returns a list containing an array of string while, in reality, you are just returning a single column (no array needed) and the values are probably decimals that are converted to strings and probably are converted back to decimals when you use them. And we don't even start talking about dates. Do you see how this method propagates its problem through all your application?

If you want a general solution then choose a good ORM that abstract the use of a database and return data properly converted to object instances. Check for [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx) or [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) (but many other exist)

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem~ But I also have other methods to retrieve single values (like the ExecuteScalar sample) and other types and this is not a _do-it-all method_, so no worries~

Answer (score 0):

The `AffectedRows` property should not be used with `SELECT` statements, since it is only meaningful when `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements are used. The following should fix your issue:

```
Int32 fields = reader.FieldCount;
List<String[]> records = new List<String[]>()

while (reader.Read())
{
    String[] row = new String[fields];

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < fields; ++i)
        row[i] = reader.GetString(i);

    records.Add(row);
}
```